# copy constructor called in the constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

If I have the classes:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include "connection.h"
class Request{
private:
    size_t sz;
    char *data;
    Connection *connection;
public:
    Request(const char* d, size_t s, const Connection &c);
    Request& operator=(const Request &other);
    Request(const Request &rhs);
    ~Request();
    void print();
    void setElement(size_t, char);
};
```

```
#include <cstddef>
#ifndef CONNECTION_HPP
#define CONNECTION_HPP
class Connection {
private:
    size_t *priority;
    size_t *count;
public:
    Connection(size_t p): priority(new size_t(p)), count(new size_t(1)) {};
    Connection(const Connection&);
    Connection& operator=(const Connection&);
    ~Connection();
    size_t getPriority();
    void setPriority(size_t); };
#endif
```

I provide the constructor of the class request:

```
Request::Request(const char* d, size_t s, const Connection& c): 
sz(s), data(new char[s]),connection(new Connection(c)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i<s; ++i)
        data[i] = d[i]; }
```

When there is `connection(new Connection(c))`   I am using the copy constructor of the class connection but I don't understand why. Is the copy constructor called by `new Connection(c)` or by `connection(*)`?

Comment: How else do you expect `new Connection(c)` to construct the new object? Also, please don't use pointers and `new` everywhere. It is almost never necessary and should be avoided. See the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). I have no idea why `priority` and `count` are pointers at all, `data` should be a `std::string` and `connection` should also likely not be a pointer.

Comment: Does it even make sense for a `Request` to make a copy of a `Connection` rather than just point at the original `Connection`?

Answer (score 0):

`new Connection(c)` takes an existing Connection `c`, copies it, and gives you a raw, unmanaged pointer to that copy. Initializing the pointer `Request::c` only sets a pointer, and does not involve copy constructors.

But see the comments - this class probably has too many pointers. If `Connection` is a base class with virtual methods, you could consider a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<Connection>`, but likely `Request::c` should be an ordinary `Connection` member.